# Why is fscanf() seg faulting while trying to read from a file?

Tags: c

I am using C in Visual Studio via a remote Linux server. I want to read a file and store the contents in a array of structs. Every time I try to read a line using `fscanf()` it seg faults. Thanks in advance.

Format of the file I'm trying to read:

```
F150    5.4 28000 white
RAM1500 5.7 32000 orange
car     4.5 12000 green
truck   6.1 55000 black
```

Here's a simplified version my program as the other parts function fine:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct data {
    char name[20];
    float floatNum;
    int intNum;
    char color[20];
} temp;

int scan(void) {
    int size = 0;
    FILE *data;
    data = fopen("./hw3.data", "r");
    while (1) {
        fscanf(data, "%s %f %d %s", temp.name, &temp.floatNum,
               &temp.intNum, temp.color);
        if (feof(data))
            break;
        size++;
    }
    return size;
}

void load(int size, struct data autos[]) {
    int i;
    FILE *data;
    data = fopen("./hw3.data", "r");
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        fscanf(data, "%s %f %d %s", autos[i].name, &autos[i].floatNum,
               &autos[i].intNum, autos[i].color);
    }
}

int main() {
    int size;
    struct data *autos;
    size = scan();
    autos = malloc(size * sizeof(struct data));
    load(size, autos);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: One potential problem: you're not checking to see if `fopen` succeeded.

Comment: Not related to the problem, but you should close your files when you're done reading.

Comment: You should make sure that `data` is not `NULL`. You'll get a segfault if the `fopen()` failed.

Comment: I compiled your program and it ran fine, without errors.  Then I renamed `hw3.data` to something else (so it couldn't be found by that name), and then I got a segfault, too.

Comment: Always use the return value from `fscanf` to check for success. it might fail, and still not be EOF. So the first `while` loop should be `while (fscanf(data, "%s %f %d %s", . . .) == 4) { size++; }`

Comment: Aside: you forgot to `fclose` or to `rewind` the file. Open the file once, and pass the file pointer, or, pass the name as an argument. If you start repeating hard coded data you'll get maintenance issues.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple possible causes for problems:

- you do not test if `fopen()` succeeds: if the file cannot be opened, the `FILE` pointer `data` will be null, causing undefined behavior in `fscanf()`, possibly a seg fault.
- you do not test if `malloc` succeeds... again causing a seg fault if memory cannot be allocated.
- you should close the `FILE` after reading
- your test for `feof()` is incorrect: it might be true after successfully reading the last item, causing it to be ignored and you might never reach the end of file if one of the items cannot be read. You should just test the return value of `fscanf()`: it returns the number of successful conversions, so `4` in your case.
- you should use `%19s` to avoid writing beyond the end of the targets arrays, another potential source of undefined behavior.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct data {
    char name[20];
    float floatNum;
    int intNum;
    char color[20];
};

int scan(const char *filename) {
    struct data temp;
    int size = 0;
    FILE *data = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (data == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot open %s: %s\n", filename, strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }
    while (fscanf(data, "%19s %f %d %19s",
                  temp.name, &temp.floatNum,
                  &temp.intNum, temp.color) == 4) {
        size++;
    }
    fclose(data);
    return size;
}

int load(const char *filename, int size, struct data autos[]) {
    int i;
    FILE *data = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (data == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot open %s: %s\n", filename, strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (fscanf(data, "%19s %f %d %19s",
                   autos[i].name, &autos[i].floatNum,
                   &autos[i].intNum, autos[i].color) != 4)
            break;
    }
    fclose(data);
    return i;
}

int main() {
    char filename[] = "./hw3.data";
    int size = scan(filename);
    if (size < 0)
        return 1;
    if (size > 0) {
        struct data *autos = malloc(size * sizeof(struct data));
        if (autos == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "cannot allocate %zu bytes\n", size * sizeof(struct data));
            return 1;
        }
        int n = load(filename, size, autos);
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            printf("%s %g %d %s\n", autos[i].name, autos[i].floatNum,
                   autos[i].intNum, autos[i].color);
        }
        free(autos);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment:  The "Friends of Zero"  are upset with `if (size <= 0) return 1;`  Zero has feelings too, just like the respected 1, 2, 3,...  Sure zero means nothing to many, yet at FoZ, its something.  Suggest `if (size < 0)`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: OK, empty file, or no valid records should not cause `EXIT_FAILURE`, but attempting to allocate 0 bytes should be avoided too.

Comment: @DavidRanieri: cut+paste mishap... fixed! thank you for proof reading.